# Create GWT project with unique url

Tags: url, gwt, unique, history

I am working GWT project which using  History Class(com.google.gwt.user.client.History). Now the project work well. But the customer want the project run with unique url for security.
I tried to investigate the way to use the GWT History with a unique url but no luck.
If you know the solution, please give me the suggestion. Thank so much.

Comment: What is unique url? does it mean that you cannot use hash marks? what are the security issues?

Comment: When I use the GWT History, The url for the one view will be appended the history token.
Example: Login view: http://localhost:8082/firstproject/#login. 
Now the customer want the url for all view is unique url: http://localhost:8082/firstproject/.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the History implementation in GWT is based on hash fragments so if you remove that part (for instance overriding the `nativeUpdate()` method in `HistoryImpl` your app will never be notified when the state changes.

The solution I see is to override the History mechanism in GWT with your own based on the `window.history.pushState()` HTML5 API. It is supported by modern browsers (not IE9).

With push state you can change the state of the browser with and without changing the url.

There is an implementation of History based on [pushState at gitHub](https://github.com/jbarop/gwt-pushstate/tree/master/src). Johannes Barop gave a presentation of this project in the gwt-meetup 2013, videos are not avaliable yet (they will be in few days though). I think it does not implements your edge case of not changing the url, but probably it should be easy to add, or ask him at github.